# how to use {{}} expression inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm using Fire base to retrieve the user object, inside the object there is type which is admin or normal user.

```
$scope.User=$firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refUser().child(user.uid));
```

now i'm trying to use ng-if to change the view of each user

```
<div ng-if="{{User.type}}==admin">
```

i have tried another approach by changing the field to admin either true or false

```
<div ng-if="!{{User.admin}}">
```

but still not working in both cases, the problem is i think in using {{}} inside the ng-if directive

Comment: all of the built-in angular directives support expressions without needing to use interpolation (aka {{}}). So simply say `ng-if="!User.admin"` or `ng-if="User.type === "admin"`

Comment: All except for `ng-src`, `ng-srcset`, and `ng-href` which **are** interpolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont usally use {{}} in directives. Just the following code would be sufficient:

```
<div ng-if="!User.admin">
```

Answer (score 1):

The ng-if directive removes the HTML element if the expression evaluates to false.

If the if statement evaluates to true, a copy of the Element is added in the DOM.

The ng-if directive is different from the ng-hide, which hides the display of the element, where the ng-if directive completely removes the element from the DOM.

Hence, both of given is correct:

```
    <div ng-if="User.type==admin">

    <div ng-if="!User.admin">
```